# Ajax call never returns

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: urlToGetRules,
            data: { ruleName: ruleName},
        })
             .success(function (data) {
                 document.location.href = "/StudentRules/GetAllStudentRules?productId=test";
             })
             .fail(function (xhr) {
                 alert("Something went wrong!!!")
                 console.log(xhr.responseText);
             });
```

In my controller I am creating a document in DocDb like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpsertDoc(string ruleName)
{
            StudentRule studentRule = new StudentRule() { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), StudentId = "test", Name = ruleName, RuleType = "Allow all updates", StartDate = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString() };
            _updateScheduleRulesManager.UpsertScheduleRule(studentRule);

            return Json(new { success = true });
}
```

The idea is to return to a page where I list all the rules once the user creates a new rule in the Add Rule page.

The above code executes fine and I can see the expected document in Docdb but the status for this call in Developer Tools shows 'pending'!!!
The code in the Success never executes.

Can someone please guide me here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens when you debug the controller method? Does it ever hit that `return` line?

Comment: It does hit the controller.

Comment: Regardless of whether it hits the controller, can you put a breakpoint on the `return` line, does it hit? It could be update statement that's hanging.

Comment: If I remove your Database update code and only keep  return Json(new { success = true }); then your code works fine so looks like there is some error in your update code.

Comment: @mattytommo You on here again? :)

Comment: @hutchonoid Can't have you catching up to me ;)

Comment: @mattytommo No chance of that mate. :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no `.success` handler.

> Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and
>   jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare
>   your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(),
>   and jqXHR.always() instead.

You need to use done:

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("UpsertDoc")',
        data: { ruleName: 'test'},
        }).done(function (data) {
            document.location.href = "/StudentRules/GetAllStudentRules?productId=test";            
        }).fail(function (xhr) {
        alert("Something went wrong!!!")
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
        });
```

Also remove the spacing before the `.done` and `.fail`.

**Screen shot**

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: I thought that was some dodgy bracketing on the OP's code (thought it was a pasting error), didn't realise he was using this syntax! Good spot ;)

Comment: How is that a "good spot"?  Outside of personal aesthetics, does it make any actual difference?

Comment: @ToddGrigsby The version of jQuery didn't have a `success` method, so it would never work. Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

i think there is problem you are not passinb `productid` in request check this in ajax call

```
data: { ruleName: ruleName},
```

no productid in it where as in you method productid is parameter

```
public ActionResult UpsertDoc(string ruleName, string productId)
```

your data element should be and add datatype

```
data: { ruleName: 'name of rule', productId: 'productid' }, 
datatype : 'json'
```

Comment: Whilst you're right, that won't make any difference to the issue he's experiencing.

Comment: @mattytommo - if that is so than need to debug the code ..also need to check url is correct and degguer hits method call i.e. action method

Comment: As I said, it does hit the breakpoint and the databae op is a success but the call never returns to the success.